# JavaScript in a PHP Functions

Tags: php, javascript, function

Well I have a JS function that works like this:

```
    $.msgBox({
       title:"msgbox",
       content:"whatever"
    });
```

And I want to use it inside a PHP Function.

I tried this:

```
function MsgBox(){
        echo'<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/JQuery/jquery.msgBox.js">$.msgBox({title:"msgbox", content:"whatever"});</script>';
    }
```

so on a button OnClick event will prompt the messagebox:

```
<input name="button" type="button" onclick="MsgBox();"/>
```

But nothing happens when I click it.
What can I do? to make it work?
Hope anyone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that's possible

Comment: Why you create `MsgBox()` in PHP ? And you can't call PHP-Function in JavaScript without any API or REST interface.

Comment: You cant call a PHP function using jquery !!

Comment: ^^ you sort of can with ajax, but that's not the issue here, you should create a js function MsgBox

Comment: Thanks to all for the replies.
I'm learning OOP PHP so I was wondering if I was able to call the JS Function inside a PHP one but seems like it's impossible, btw, I got the script from this page http://jquerymsgbox.ibrahimkalyoncu.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: Why does the PHP (or other server side) code in my Javascript not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/reference-why-does-the-php-or-other-server-side-code-in-my-javascript-not-wor)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function MsgBox(){
        echo'<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/JQuery/jquery.msgBox.js">$.msgBox({title:"msgbox", content:"whatever"});
MsgBox();</script>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would only work if you'd make the javascript inside the echo a function, and you would run the PHP function in your PHP code.

You can't call PHP functions from the client, for obvious reasons. However, what you can do is use AJAX, but in my (uneducated) guess of your situation, I would rather suggest just putting the JS function in your HTML code, rather than in PHP.